# Как исправить ошибку сегментирования в С?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память

У меня есть двумерный динамический массив, состоящий, например, из 2 строк и 3 столбцов:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Суть задачи: перевернуть наш исходный массив на 90 градусов, то есть в нашем случае сделать массив из 3 строк и 2 столбцов:

```
4 1 
5 2 
6 3
```

Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  int N, M;
  int **array;
  int **newArray;

  printf("Введите числа N и M: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

  array = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      array[i] = (int *)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
          printf("array[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
          scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
          printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");

  newArray = (int **)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      newArray[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  }

  printf("%d %d \n", M, N);
  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      int n2 = N - 1;
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
          newArray[i][j] = array[n2][i];
          printf("%d ", newArray[i][j]);
          n2--;
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Заполнение первого массива при указанных выше параметрах происходит без проблем, второй массив поначалу тоже спокойно заполняется, но на 3 строке нового массива вылетает *segmentation fault 11*. Если я забиваю в первоначальный массив 3 строки и 2 столбца, то та же ошибка вылетает после заполнения 5 из 6 ячеек.

Если я выделяю под оба массива в 2 раза больше памяти, всё работает нормально.

Comment: Возьмите в привычку выделять память для массива через идиому `p = malloc(n * sizeof *p)` и такие глупые ошибки пропадут сами собой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не в 64-битной системе работаете? кроме выделения памяти

```
array = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

вместо верного

```
array = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
```

(и то же самое для второй матрицы) вроде ошибок нет.

Можно, правда, обойтись без `n2` в цикле, и все же хорошо бы убирать за собой (читай - освобождать память), но это уже мелочи.